# Coherent states and thermal properties

Tags: thermodynamics, density-operator, research-level, partition-function, coherent-states

I am reading a paper called [Thermodynamics of Coherent States and Black Hole Entropy](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0104083.pdf), written by Bashkirov and Sukhanov. If I understand correctly, they define a coherent state by the equation
$$a|d\rangle=d\ \Big(\frac{m\omega}{2\hbar}\Big)^{1/2}|d\rangle$$
where $d$ is a complex number, and together with the factor $\big(\frac{m\omega}{2\hbar}\big)^{1/2}$, they comprise the eigenvalue of the annihilation operator on the eigenstates $|d\rangle$. The authors, then, construct a density matrix $\rho^d=|d\rangle\langle d|$, whose diagonal elements are given by
$$\rho^d_{ff}=|\langle f|d\rangle|^2=\exp\Big(-\frac{m\omega|d|^2}{2\hbar}\Big)
\exp\Big(\frac{m\omega}{2\hbar}[-|f|^2+d^{*}f+df^{*}]\Big)$$
Now, I quote the authors saying that

> The first multiplier doesn’t depend on the index f and thus it can be considered as a
> normalizing factor, that is, a reverse value of the partition function

So, I realize that there is the inverse of some sort of partition function to be defined here. Why, however, is it defined like that? What does the fact that $Q_d=e^{\bar{n}_d}=\exp(m\omega|d|^2/2\hbar)$ not depending on the index $f$ have anything to do with the latter factor playing the role of a partition function? What is the ensemble here? Is this element of the density matrix the probability of being in a particular state of the density matrix with a fixed amount $\bar{n}_d$ of particles, present in the coherent state? How can one relate all this with thermodynamics?

Thanks!

Comment: If $|f\rangle$ is also a coherent state, then the overlap would produce an exponential function with an exponent in terms of the two parameters. One term would be independent of $f$. However, the expression you provide does not seem to be what one would expect for such a case.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the reply @flippiefanus . From what I read from the paper, I think $|f\rangle$ is a coherent state as well. What would one expece in such cases?

Comment: $\langle\alpha|\beta\rangle = \exp(-|\alpha|^2/2-|\beta|^2/2+\alpha^*\beta)$

Comment: Well, if you squre this, you will have something of this form I think...

Comment: What about the statistical mechanics of the setup? Can you elaborate on that?? How is the overall exponential factor the inverse of some sort of partition function?

Comment: The short answer is that, taken at face value, it has nothing to do with any ensemble or thermodynamics in general. They make a vague intuitive analogy based on the completeness of coherent states. The latter says that $\int d f | f\rangle\langle f| = 1$, and hence, $\int df \rho^d_{ff} = 1$. So, the integral of the second exponent of your second formula over f has to give $e^{\overline{n}_d}$. This very much looks like the definition of the partition function $Z = \int df e^{-\beta E_f}$, where $E_f$ would be the energy of the system. The point made by the authors is no deeper than this.

Comment: Here the role of $\beta E_f$ would be played by $\frac{m\omega}{2 \hbar} [|f|^2 - d^*f - d f^*]$.

Comment: Hi @KarenHovhannisyan and thanks for the reply. Okay, fair enough, but can't someone argue that there is some sort of ensemble of states, say energy eigenstates, each with their own statistical "weight", and therefore derive an expression for a partition function and finally an expression for a temperature? Would this temperature correspond to something physical if the abovementioned steps take place?