# Coherent States and Temperature for Scalar QFT with Source

Tags: quantum-field-theory, harmonic-oscillator, research-level, coherent-states, thermal-field-theory

This is a follow-up question on a question I previously asked, namely [Coherent states and thermal properties](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/757442/coherent-states-and-thermal-properties?noredirect=1#comment1696549_757442). The authors of the article I am referring to in the previous question ([Thermodynamics of Coherent States and Black Hole Entropy](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0104083.pdf)), after deriving an expression for some sort of temperature in coherent states in the framework of QM, they then move to doing the same in QFT. So, they consider a scalar massive theory coupled to some source.
$$\Big(\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}-\nabla^2+
\frac{m^2c^2}{\hbar^2}\Big)\phi(t,\vec{r})=g\rho(\vec{r})$$

Then, they proceed in defining a density operator, say $\rho^d=|d\rangle\langle d|$, where $|d\rangle$ are normalized coherent states, satisfying $a_{\vec{k}_i}|d\rangle=(m_{\vec{k}_i}\omega_{\vec{k}_i}/2\hbar)^{1/2}d_{\vec{k}_i}|d\rangle$ (this is my assumption and it is based on the author's approach in the first part of the paper, where they define the corresponding states in a QM framework). Then, one can define the mean occupation numbers as $\bar{n}_{\vec{k}_i}=\langle d|a^{\dagger}_{\vec{k}_i}a_{\vec{k}_i}|d\rangle=(m_{\vec{k}_i}\omega_{\vec{k}_i}/2\hbar)|d_{\vec{k}_i}|^2$, the partition function etc etc.

However, the part I do not understand is the expression for the expected energy. The author's expression is
$$E_{KGF}=\bar{n}\hbar\bar{\omega}+\frac{1}{2}\hbar\bar{\omega}$$
and then use this to derive an expression for the temperature...

I tried deriving this expression in the following way: fist, assume a Hamiltonian of the form $H=\sum_i\hbar\omega_{\vec{k}_i}(a^{\dagger}_{\vec{k}_i}a_{\vec{k}_i}+\frac{1}{2})$ and then calculate the expectation value using normalized coherent states
$$\langle d|H|d\rangle=\sum_i\hbar\omega_{\vec{k}_i}(\langle d|a^{\dagger}_{\vec{k}_i}a_{\vec{k}_i}|d\rangle+\frac{1}{2}\langle d|d\rangle)\\
=\sum_i\hbar\omega_{\vec{k}_i}(\bar{n}_{\vec{k}_i}+\frac{1}{2})\\
=\hbar\bar{\omega}\bar{n}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_i\hbar\omega_{\vec{k}_i}$$
where $\bar{n}=\sum_i\bar{n}_{\vec{k}_i}$ (**presumably, since $n=\sum_in_{\vec{k}_i}$**) and $\bar{\omega}=\sum_i\omega_{\vec{k}_i}\bar{n}_{\vec{k}_i}/\bar{n}$. An alternative approach would be to consider
$$E_{KGF}=\sum_n\rho_{nn}\langle n|H|n\rangle$$
but it still yields the same results...

My second term does not match the author's second term and I thing I am not missing something "calculation-wise". Am I missing something that has to do with the conceptual understanding of the derivation? I quote their statement/argument for writing down this expression

> An energy of virtual quanta is presented as the sum of energies of harmonic oscillators of
> the frequencies $\omega_{\vec{k}_i}$ and mean occupation numbers $\bar{n}_{\vec{k}_i}$
> $$E_{KGF}=\bar{n}\hbar\bar{\omega}+\frac{1}{2}\hbar\bar{\omega}$$

So, what is going on here? Can someone help? Why doesn't my second term match theirs? Also, I would expect the entropy derivation to contain a derivative with respect to the temperature, but instead, it is equal to $2k_B\bar{n}$. I do not know why is that...

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: There may be something wrong in the paper. The second term is obviously the vacuum energy. It should be a sum over all frequencies and not the average of the frequency, unless I understand the physics incorrectly.

Comment: Hi @flippiefanus. I think I agree with you, but I am not 100% certain. But is it possible for a paper to contain such a mistake?? Maybe the authors mean something else by $\bar{n}$? Maybe it is some sort of average of the average occupation numbers $\bar{n}_i$, i.e. $\sum_i\bar{n}_i/\text{Vol}$, where $\text{Vol}$ is the number of $i-$ sites? I am tempted to accept that the second term should be substituted by the total energy of the zero modes, but I am a bit unsure...

Comment: And another thing I do not understand is the derivation for the temperature... I would expect the entropy derivation to contain a derivative with respect to the temperature, but instead, it is equal to $2k_b\bar{n}$. I do not know why is that...

Comment: Normally, the vacuum energy is divergent. If it is the average then it won't be divergent. I don't see anything from the context that would explain why the vacuum energy should be finite.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it is probably a mistake in the paper! Now I am convinced:) Thanks a lot @flippiefanus. But, wait, is it also divergent even if one divides by the volume? Yes, right?